# validate ActiveRecord field with especific class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I want to validate that my field is from an especific class.

Concrete example. I have a model that must by unique *by day*. So, I insert a validation

```
validates :my_date_field, uniqueness: {scope: [:scope_one, :scope_two]}
```

If I create my record with a Date, the validation works fine. If I create my record with a Time, however, (my tests use Time::now) it parses it to a Date, but does not trigger the validation.

How should I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

--Edit--
A related problem:

How I forbid someone to do
    MyModel::create my_date_field: 4

? It is passing the validate_presence from active_record, passing the null: false from migration, and saving an ugly 4 in my date_field.

I'm completely lost here =\

Comment: Well, I solved it using a before_validation where I manually made my parsing, or added an error.
But I'll keep the question, waiting for a better answer. Moderation can delete it, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord will type-cast your values to whatever type it thinks is appropriate for the underlying database field.  You can still access the original type, though, via `my_date_field_before_type_cast`.  The `*_before_type_cast` accessors exist for every attribute.  There you can check the class or do any other conversions you might need.  These are available in custom validation methods as well.

Comment: A workaround, indeed. But there is not a helper, like, say, `force_type :my_field, SomeClass` ?